Are there any "Devtools" for Swing?
Are there any "Devtools" for Swing (or anything, really, that can ease the process of mapping GUI elements to Java objects in code)?
As of now, it's quite time-consuming to locate a Swing component responsible for a specific form or button. I mean I know that a text field is JTextField, a button is a JButton, etc., but still in a mature production app it's a real pain to identify an associated component and a particular listener if a certain element doesn't work as expected (or its functionality has to be modified). Typically, it involves a clever use of the IntelliJ debugger, it's not fast
Is there anything at all that can simplify that process?
